# Shape problems in LSTM; Configuring LSTM properly in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

So I wanted to make a neural network that predicts weather on python. It should take data on previous 30 days as input and make a prediction on how many % (+ or -) will the air temperature change. Neural network will compute 2 inputs, so data on a single day looks like this:

1-st input:
**[20, 72, 1]**

First entry is temperature, second is humidity and third is atmospheric pressure.

2-nd input:
[**Weather observations**]

[**Weather observations**] array contains long strings of weather observations. In this array there may be one observation, may be more than one or none.

One complete unit of training data for 30-ty days looks like this:

1-st input:

```
  [ [20, 72, 1], #1-st day
    [15, 89, 1.03], #2-nd day
    [19, 79, 1.01], #3-d day
    [24, 67, 0.98], #...
    ...
    ... ]
```

2-nd input:

```
  [ ["Many cloudy spots...", "Today we had experienced..."], #1-st day
    ["Rain has been going for..."], #2-nd day
    [""], #3-d day
    ["In following regions...", "Cause of geomagnetic...", "Today is one of the sunniest...], #...
    ...
    ... ]
```

So both of those input units contains thirty entries like this (becuase of mentioned 30-ty days), and the label for this unit is how much one week ahead the air temperature has changed in % compared to the last entry.

Summarizing, the inputs will be lists of lists, where each list contains device readings/weather observations for 30 days with daily readings/observations placed in another list inside. So, first element in the second group of 30 days will be a set of observations which is second element in the first group of 30 days (aka 3-rank list, I hope you got it).

I wrote this model:

```
    embedding_dim = 128  
    vocab_size = len(words_to_int)  # number of unique words

    num_input = keras.Input(shape= (30,3), name="nums")
    nmlstm = layers.LSTM(64)(num_input) #num input goes to num lstm
    nmdense = layers.Dense(64)(nmlstm) #num lstm goes to num dense

    text_input = keras.Input(shape= (30, max_sequence_length), name="text") #basically length of the longest string observation sequence 
    text_vec = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)(text_input) #text input goes to text embedding
    txlstm = layers.LSTM(64)(text_vec) #text embedding goes to text lstm


    united = layers.concatenate([nmdense, txlstm]) #concatenating text lstm and num dense
    almostlast = layers.Dense(64)(united) #computing united input 
    last = layers.Dense(2, name='prediction')(almostlast) #output dense layer

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[num_input, text_input], outputs=last)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy)
    model.fit({"nums": X1_train, "text": X2_train}, {"prediction": y_train}, epochs=8, batch_size=10)
```

When I try to run the code, I get this error:

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 30, 2, 128)
```

I tried changing the input shape of text_input, but I kept on getting the same error.
To mention, I didn't have any problems on encoding data, padding it etc. Also it's better if there's a way of fixing it without changing the shape of 2-nd input data because the main goal is to make the neural network treat 30-day data as one input and providing only one output (how many % (+ or -) the air temperature will change) while learning on text observations to make predictions also based on them.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - print all the input/output shapes. You should clearly know your X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test shapes. For np arrays is print(X_train.shape).

Second, you define the input to the NN as `num_input = keras.Input(shape= (30,3), name="nums")` where it's a 3 d input - considering the batch size None. You should reshape your input data, because the input to LSTM is only defined by (Batch,memory,features).

Additionally, use return_sequences=True inside the LSTM layer and then use layers.Flatten()(x) - to avoid confusion in transitions between layers.(just a hint).

Good luck.

Comment: Perhaps you could include some example code to improve this answer?